# Can I claim GST/HST Input Tax Credits (ITCs) on Uber, taxi, or limousine fares?

Tags: canada, expenses, hst, tax-credit, gst

Uber invoices do not include a GST/HST number, and tax is not separated. On the other hand, Uber drivers ARE required to be registered for GST/HST and collect & remit the tax.

http://barretttaxlaw.com/uber-gsthst-issue/

Can I rely on the fact that the driver is required to be registered, and assume that they are in fact including the tax, and therefore claim an input tax credit?

Note: CRA provides instructions for working backwards to calculate GST/HST on a tax-included fare here:

http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/tpcs/gst-tps/txlmsn/menu-eng.html

Comment: In all jurisdictions in Canada, Uber is currently operating illegally. This may change after March 1, 2016, in Edmonton, Alberta. Given that drivers are in almost all circumstances not properly licensed and do not have proper insurance, I think it's more than a stretch to believe the driver has registered for GST/HST or are submitting the amount they owe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Canada Revenue Agency describes in detail [here](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/tpcs/gst-tps/bspsbch/itc-cti/nvc-eng.html) what information businesses must generally include on their invoices so that GST/HST registrants can claim Input Tax Credits (ITCs) for the expenses. Quote:

> **Sales invoices for GST/HST registrants**
>
> You have to give customers who are GST/HST registrants specific
>   information on the invoices, receipts, contracts, or other business
>   papers that you use when you provide taxable goods and services. This
>   information lets them support their claims for input tax credits
>   (ITCs) or rebates for the GST/HST you charged. [...]

The page quoted continues with a table describing what, specifically, needs to be on a sales invoice based on the total amount of the invoice; the requirements differ for: total sale under $30, total sale between $30 to $149.99, and total sale $150 or more.

For the total sale under $30 category, the only things a sales invoice *must* contain to support an ITC claim are (1) the provider's business name, (2) the invoice date, and (3) the total amount paid/payable. i.e. When the total sale is under $30, there is no requirement for any GST/HST amount to be indicated separately, nor for a business number to be present on the invoice.

Hence, IMHO (and I am neither an accountant nor a lawyer), if your Uber rides are for $30 or less, then you shouldn't expect a GST/HST number anyway, and a simple invoice as described should be enough for you to claim your ITCs. Whether or not the provider is registered in fact for GST/HST is beside the point.

For amounts over $30, you need a bit more. While the page above specifies that the provider's business number should be included beginning with the next level of total sales,  there are exceptions to those rules described at another page mentioned, [Exceptions to invoice requirements](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/tpcs/gst-tps/bspsbch/itc-cti/xcptnstnvc-eng.html), that specifically apply to the taxi/limousine case. Quote:

> **Exceptions to invoice requirements**
>
> GST/HST registrants are required to keep the necessary documentation
>   to support their claim for ITCs and rebates. In certain circumstances
>   the documentation requirements have been reduced.
>
> [...]
>
> **For taxi or limousine fares your books and records must show:**
>
> - the supplier's name or trade name;
> - the date of the supply;
> - the fare; and
> - *the amount of GST/HST charged, or a statement that the fare includes GST/HST.*  [emphasis mine]

So at a minimum, for fare in excess of $30 total, you should ask the driver to note *either* (a) the amount of GST/HST charged, or (b) a statement that the fare includes GST/HST. The driver's business number need not be specified. Consequently, if your receipt for a ride in excess of $30 does not contain any such additional information with respect to GST/HST, then I would expect the receipt does not satisfy the CRA's requirements for supporting your ITC claim.

i.e. Keep your individual rides under $30 each, or else get a better receipt from the driver when it is above that amount.

p.s. It should go without saying, but your rides, of course, must be considered reasonable business expenses in order to qualify for GST/HST ITCs for your business. Receipts for rides of a personal nature are not eligible, so be sure to maintain proper records as to the business purpose and destination for each ride receipt so claimed.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Canadians have not been paying any tax on Uber rides, and will only begin to do so on July 1, 2017.

Source: http://mobilesyrup.com/2017/03/22/uber-canada-gst-hst-budget-2017/

Comment: This article is somewhat inaccurate. Uber has been collecting GST and QST in Montreal at least, and possibly elsewhere in Quebec: https://www.uber.com/en-CA/drive/montreal/get-started/tax-registration/ Furthermore, Uber drivers were meant to be submitting their GST in other provinces, too, though obviously the vast majority of them weren't.